# UWP native toolchain build occassionally fails with ILC error ILC1300: Error Invalid access to memory location

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, x86, msbuild, 64-bit

We are working on a Xamarin.Forms app that targets UWP (Universal Windows Platform). To get the best performance and submit the app to Windows Store, we had to enable the native toolchain build. Our app targets x86|x64|ARM.

We use the following MSBuild script to compile the app

```
msbuild.exe OUR.UWP.csproj /nologo /nr:false `
/property:projectname="Our-Project" `
/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|arm" `
/p:Platform="x64" `
/p:AppxPackageDir="AppxPackages_Staging" `
/p:AppxBundle=Always `
/p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode="StoreUpload" `
/p:PackageCertificateThumbprint="***" `
/p:PackageCertificateKeyFile="***.pfx" `
/p:PackageCertificatePassword="***" `
/p:Verbosity=detailed `
/p:configuration="Release" /m
```

In our build infrastructure, which uses Azure Pipelines in combination with Azure Virtual Machine scale sets, we are occasionally getting the following error:

```
LOGGERBASEDEXECTASK : ILC error ILC1300: Error while copying file 'C:\a\1\s\**\**.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.winmd' to 'C:\a\1\s\QQPad.Mobile\QQPad.Mobile.UWP\bin\x64\Release\x86\ilc\Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.winmd': Invalid access to memory location : 'C:\a\1\s\**\**.UWP\bin\x64\Release\x86\ilc\Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.winmd' [C:\a\1\s\**\**.UWP\**.UWP.csproj]
```

We are building the app inside the Azure Virtual Machine scale set. Initially, the scale set was based on 16 Core / 64GB VMs with Visual Studio 2022 and Windows Server.
We would get this error during the native compilation almost on every build. Somewhere (I couldn't find that link again to put it here), I found that the issue is because the native toolset has a utility that is 32-bit (even though we specify the build to use a 64-bit toolset). When there's an abundance of cores, there are a lot of parallel operations, which also spikes the RAM. The process crashes when the consumed memory reaches the 4GB threshold (the max for 32-bit process).

And indeed, after we switched to virtual machines with 8 Cores and 32GB of RAM (D8as_v5 machines), the build became much more stable. However, we are still getting the same error from time to time. Considering the build takes 40 minutes, getting it to fail occasionally and delay releases is an absolute productivity killer.

Is there anything that can be done to resolve this error for good?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience.
As cpu performance, number of cores and memory size increase, native compilation becomes more and more unstable. I managed to increase the stability in the following way:

In VS select "Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run".
Set "MSBuild project output verbosity" to Detailed.
Check "Run build at low process priority".

Generating of large amount of text output and low process priority seem to delay the execution of some threads involved in native compilation and that makes the whole process more stable.
My experience is that building time does not increase significantly in this way.
It has been tested on a 16-core (32-thread) physical machine with 64 GB ram.